# Doubts on remote access on Ubuntu 12.10 via FreeNX

Tags: 12.10, remote-access, freenx, remote-login

I'm currently a little confused: what I'd like to do is to remotely access my Ubuntu 12.10 machine from an external device. I thought it would be straightforward, but I'm finding lots of issues and a scarcity of help.

Looking around I was finally able to pin-down the solution to FreeNX: it should be able to give me remote control over my machine with visual interface (not command-line). The problem is that its installation is a real hell: I tried to follow both [official ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) and different tutorials (such as this [one](http://blog.terranux.net/2013/02/run-and-configure-freenx-on-ubuntu-12-10/) which should be specifically tailored on Ubuntu 12.10), but I always ended up with errors and a non-functioning server.

Is there somebody who was able to create a functioning FreeNX server on Ubuntu 12.10? How did you made it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great post about it:

http://blog.terranux.net/2013/02/run-and-configure-freenx-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.